# Representations of the dual Banach algebra pair $(\ell_1,c_0)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $\displaystyle E_p=(\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \ell^1_n)_{\ell^p}$ for some $1<p<\infty$ and $\ell^1 = \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ be equipped with the convolution. Then, there exists an isometric & weak$^*$ continuous representation $\pi:\ell^1\to B(E_p)$ (please see below for details).

Suppose $F$ is another reflexive Banach space for which there exists an isometric & weak$^*$ continuous representation $\pi_2:\ell^1\to B(F)$.

> **Question:** Is $E_p$ linearly isomorphic to a subspace of $F$ for some $1<p<\infty$?

---

**Details**:
$\displaystyle E_p=(\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \ell^1_n)_{\ell^p}$ and $\ell^1 = \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ is equipped with the convolution $$\forall x=(\xi_n), y=(\eta_n)\in\ell^1 \hspace{12mm} (x*y)_j = \sum_{k=0}^j \xi_{j-k}\eta_k \hspace{6mm}\forall j\in\mathbb{N}$$

With abuse of notation, for $x\in\ell^1$ and $y\in\ell^1_n$, let's write
$$(x*y)_j = \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
\sum_{k=0}^j \xi_{j-k}\eta_k &; j=0,\dots,n \\
0 &; j>n \\
\end{array}\right.$$
We use the same notation when both $x,y\in\ell^1_n$; that is, we pad $x$ with zeroes and use what we wrote above for $x*y$.

Next, for a given $x\in\ell^1$, define the map $C_x\in B(E)$ by
$$C_x y = (x*y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \hspace{12mm} \forall y = (y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in E$$
It is not difficult to show that $C_x$ is bounded & linear, $\|C_x\| = \|x\|_{\ell^1}$, and that $C_xC_y = C_{x*y}$ for all $x,y\in\ell^1$. Thus, the map $\pi:\ell^1\to B(E)$ defined by $\pi(x) = C_x$ is an isometric homomorphism.

$\pi = \phi^*$, where $\phi:E\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}}E^*\to c_0$ is defined by $$\phi(x\otimes y) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \tilde{x}_n*y_n  $$
for all $x=(x_n)\in E$, $y=(y_n)\in E^*$, and extended to $E\mathbin{\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}}E^*$ linearly and continuously. Here $\tilde{x}_n(k) = \overline{x_n(n-k)}$ for $k=0,\dots,n$. Since $\phi$ is bounded, its adjoint $\pi$ is weak$^*$ continuous.